# Webservice Data Structures

Tags: web-services, soap, webservice-client, soapui

I'm trying to Consume one SOAP webservice with SOAPUI and VB.NET to test.

But I can't understand one of the substructs SION_O_0010, it only show :

```
(...)
<SION_O_0009>aa</SION_O_0009>
<SION_O_0010 xsi:type="SI:SION_O_0010"/>
<SION_O_0011></SION_O_0011>
(...)
```

How Can I get the inner structure of SION_O_0010?

Regards,
Pedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That element is empty. There is no inner structure.

Comment: You mean that it has no values is null or the struct is not defined?

Comment: It's an empty XML element. It has no internal structure. You said you wanted to get the internal structure. There is none for you to get.

Comment: I'm sorry but I just hardcoded the structure in the webservice return and now it can't be empty, and I'm still getting the same. :(